# Write to an Excel file while it's open

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm developing a WindowsForm application where I am storing an accumulator on a destinated variable. Actually, my code is working but what I want to do now is to see the accumulator integer on an Excell cell in real-time.

So I would like to know if there is a way to write/export values from my Form to my Excel file while it is open. The idea is to see the cells being refreshed every time I send the data.

Actually, I am storing the values but with the only condition that the file is closed, so I'm curious if this is possible?

This are the actual lines of code that I have:

```
SLDocument  sl = new SLDocument (@"D:\Excel.xlsx"); sl.SetCellValue("A2","Accumulator");
sl.SetCellValue("A3", myaccumulator);
sl.Save();
```

Comment: If you share what you have so far it would be much easier to help. Definitely sounds possible to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Excel COM Library

Comment: @LuisHerrera why do you want to do that? Why update an open Excel sheet instead of displaying the data in a dashboard, grid or any other UI? If you really *really* need to automate an Excel instance, you *have* to use Excel Interop. In that case though it may be better to create an Excel plugin instead of having a separate desktop application

Comment: To be able to save/write to an Excel file, you need an exclusive access to the file (or at least your process needs to open the file first and then others can open the file in read-only).

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos well, the idea to send the information is to work with a PLC, so it can pick up the value from the Excel cell and send it to the automation process, I am extracting some areas of different pieces and doing the accumulation of them.

Comment: @LuisHerrera which means you want to send the data to the PLC, not Excel. You're using Excel as an extremely unusual communication channel. Why don't you use the PLC's API, driver or library directly? Excel knows nothing about PLCs. There's a plugin or macro in there that reads Excel sheets and talks to the PLC

Comment: @charlieface I'll check the documentation, thanks for the help :)

Comment: What you posted is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - your real problem is how to talk to a PLC and assume you need Excel for this (you don't). So when using Excel failed, you asked about Excel instead of asking about your *real* problem. As far as Excel or any automation process is concerned, Excel is just a desktop application. *Something* reads data from it and uses the PLC's or automation software's API to send the data. Why don't you send the data directtly?

Comment: Why not just connect to the Excel document with OLEDB? Treat it as a database because this is how you are trying to use it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos basically yes, but my request was to send it to an Excel file so the PLC can pick it up due the logic of the PLC program, trust me I would prefer to send it to the destinated tag, but they need it like that way, I've seen before that there's an C++ library open source that let's you interact with the PLC with C#, but I haven't used it before and I'm kinda afraid to affect the production

Comment: @A Bear I added the lines that I'm actually using to export data, let me know if you need more clarity

Comment: @LuisHerrera edit your question and explain what you want to do in the question itself. You aren't exporting data. You're trying to update an already running Excel instance. That's XY too. You think you can update a running Excel instance by exporting the data and reloading it. That's not what you really want though, and doesn't work anyway

Comment: @LuisHerrera you may still run into trouble. What you do right now is duct tape and strings. What if the changes need to be saved to disk? You'll have to make sure they're saved each time, by telling Excel to save. What if Excel isn't running or crashes? You'll have to detect that and restart it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos well yeah, that's why I'm asking if that's possible and how I can do that, I have a YouTube concept, that's why I'm consulting expertize people, I'm new on this and I want to learn how to do that. And yes, you are right, I need to refresh a cell each time they finish counting the pieces.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos well in that case there's going to be an operator always manipulating the program, so the process is kinda semi automated, the operator is going to sum the areas and when he finish he will send that to the Excel, so probably he would notice if the Excel crashes up, but for sure I Would like to automate the whole process in a future

Comment: @misha139 is this hard to do?? Literally I'm new with this, but I want to learn

Comment: @emoreau99 excellent sounds great, do you have any example, so I can get an idea?

Comment: @LuisHerrera, Excel is not a file that can be easily shared between processes. There is no code to share. What I was saying is that if your application is the first to open the Excel file, it will have write permissions. But if anything opens the file first, you will be locked in read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem in case that one of you want to handle with data as this way, i just created other File and programmed a Macro with vba to export the data of the closed File, so now I can see the cells being refreshed every time with one Click button.

Thanks for your help, regards to everyone.